# How to retrieve data exactly from database using left join?

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi everyone I have a problem.

When I input data from database is exactly but when I retrieve all the from database is not the same.?
This is the [output](http://prntscr.com/2rq8cg) from database and when I retrieve all the data the output is [this](http://prntscr.com/2rq8e1)

My question is how to output the same on the database...

MY CODES..

```
$iqry = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT a.code, a.quantity, b.itemname, b.unitmeasure 
                FROM table_inventory a LEFT JOIN table_item b ON a.id=b.id");

$iqry->execute();

$iqry->bind_result($code,$quantity,$item,$unit);
$iqry->store_result();

while ($iqry->fetch()){
  $result[] = array("code"        => $code,
                    "quantity"    => $quantity,
                    "itemname"    => $item,
                    "unitmeasure" => $unit);
}

foreach ($result as $r){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" .$r['code']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>" .$r['itemname']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>" .$r['quantity']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>" .$r['unitmeasure']. "</td>";
  echo "<td><a class='edit' href=''><img src='img/edit.png'>";
  echo "<td><a href=\"material-del.php\" class='confirm'><img src='img/delete.png'></a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $iqry = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `table_inventory`.code, `table_inventory`.quantity, `table_item`.itemname, `table_item`.unitmeasure 
                    FROM `table_inventory ` LEFT JOIN `table_item` ON table_inventory.id=table_item.id order by `table_inventory`.id");
```

May this help you.

Comment: Hi.
thanks for your help
the code and quantity is exactly but the other two tables itemname and unitmeasure are not the same.

[link](http://prntscr.com/2rqedo)